# TestNG Dataprovider size

Tags: testing, testng

Is it possible to get the number of elements in a TestNG DataProvider array at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/e4ededbe4a084795

Answer (score 0):

There is not a existing interface or method to return run time number of testng. We can add a method by ourselves to calculate the number of run time testng data provider.